# is this a bug in RadAjaxManager?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, rad-controls

I have a simple ASP.Net Webforms page in .Net 4.5 and using Telerik's ASP.Net Ajax RadControls from Q3 2016 version.

I have simple ajax scenario using RadAjaxManager. But, I am finding that every button in the updated controls of RadAjaxManager is automatically becoming an async postback trigger i.e. clicking these buttons is causing an ajax postback.

This is strange since these buttons have not been listed as AJAX initiators in RadAjaxManager's configuration.

**Question**

Is this a bug with RadAjaxManager or it's normal behavior and I am missing something?

**Code-front**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="RadAjaxManagerIssue.aspx.cs" Inherits="RadAjaxManagerIssue" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server"></telerik:RadScriptManager>
            <div>
                <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
            </div>
            <div>
                <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton1" runat="server" Text="RadButton1">
                </telerik:RadButton>

            </div>
            <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                 <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton2" runat="server" Text="RadButton2">
                </telerik:RadButton>
            </div>
            <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
                <AjaxSettings>
                    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadButton1">
                        <UpdatedControls>
                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadButton1" UpdatePanelCssClass="" />
                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadTextBox1" UpdatePanelCssClass="" />
                            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadButton2" UpdatePanelCssClass="" />
                        </UpdatedControls>
                    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                </AjaxSettings>
            </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**code-behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class RadAjaxManagerIssue : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(RadButton2);
    }
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadScriptManager1.RegisterPostBackControl(RadButton2);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you determining that RadButton2 is firing an ajax post-back and not a normal post-back?  I've tried your code, and I am seeing a difference between the two button click events.

Comment: I verified that in Google Chrome's Developer Tools under Network > XHR requests. If it were not ajax then it would not show up under XHR requests. Also, the browser does not show a loading image in tab which it does for normal postbacks.

Comment: Is the button that says RadButton2 doing a normal or ajax postback  on your end? May be its the version you are using.